# My project in Xcode do not show the code or Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a strange issue in my project, cause Xcode can not show the detail:

[image]

It is a very strange issue, and I never meet with it previously.

My Xcode is `8.2.1` version.

---

**Attention**

My Xcode if open other project, there is no issue.

---

**Attempt -1**

Clean my project

**Attempt -2**

Restart my Xcode

**Attempt -3**

Refer to Akshay Nalawade's answer, I tested but no use for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Almost 6 years after the original post and the easy solution has not been offered.  This is an incredibly frustrating issue the first time you encounter it and you're not familiar with XCode.

The Editor Pane is fully collapsed and the Debugger Pane is fully expanded.
You can fix this by clicking the Debugger Pane icon to collapse the debugger or by using the keyboard shortcut `Shift+Command+Y`

[image: Xcode debugger pane fix]

Comment: This solved my issue. Praise Jesus!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug in Xcode, never mind, you can tap `Shift-Command-K` to Clean Xcode, then close Xcode, and start again. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have tried clean project, and restart my Xcode, its no use for me.

Comment: Try to create a new project with Xcode, and if it goes well, It seems that your project configuration is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any file in Xcode and select **Open As -> Source Code**

[image]

Comment: it is not use too.

Comment: Is this happening for every project?

Comment: Other project is okay ,see my **Attention**.